# Executing a python script including GPIO commands by cron in Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi2, gpio

## Environment

- Raspberry Pi 2
- raspbian-jessie-lite
- Windows 8.1
- PuTTY 0.66 (SSH)

## Issue

Can't get cron to execute a python script with sudo. The script deals with GPIO input so it should be called with sudo. The program is supposed to save temperature and humidity to files but `cat temp.txt` and `cat humid.txt` gave me empty strings.

## crontab

`sudo crontab -e`

```
* * * * * python /home/dixhom/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/temphumid.py 1>>/tmp/cronoutput.log 2>>/tmp/cronerror.log
```

## python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import datetime

# Adafruit_DHT.DHT22 : device name
# 4 : pin number
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 4)


if humidity is not None:
        f = open("humid.txt","w")
        str = '{0}, {1}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"), humidity)
        f.write(str)

else:
        print 'Failed to get reading. Try again!'
        sys.exit(1)

if temperature is not None:
        f = open("temp.txt","w")
        str = '{0}, {1}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"), temperature)
        f.write(str)
else:
        print 'Failed to get reading. Try again!'
        sys.exit(1)
```

## cronerror.log and cronoutput.log

(empty)

## What I tried

- `sudo crontab -e`
- `/usr/bin/python` in cron
- `chkconfig cron` (cron on)
- `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo reboot`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: You can edit `/etc/crontab`. There you can specify which user shall execute the respective job in a column right after the schedule.

Option 2: Edit the crontab of `root` using

```
sudo su
crontab -e
```

I would go for the second option because this is what the [docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md) suggest...

(Disclaimer: No warranties taken regarding the GPIO stuff. I just assume you are right with the "needs sudo", because I never do GPIO on the raspi. So I referred to running a script as root only.)

Comment: Thanks. But I tried these and the issue still remained.

Comment: I assume that the script is working and producing output when called interactively. When it now runs as root, I think it will also run with root's home directory as the working directory. As the script uses relative paths, your files will be placed there...

Comment: That's right... the key was the relative path. I couldn't find the root's home directory so I fixed the program so the data is save to absolute paths and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure. Feel free to accept the answer in that case ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the relative paths. The data was save to a place different from what I was looking at.

Changing

```
f = open("humid.txt","w")
```

to

```
f = open("/home/dixhom/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/humid.txt","w")
```

solve the issue.